# i want to play a video on 2 monitors uipath

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have to play 2 videos on 2 monitors. I have to first define which is the first screen and which is the second screen. I then have to pull the video from my first screen to the second screen and make it full screen.

I have already made it the VLC format.

Comment: So, do you want to play one video as implied by the title, or two videos? How do you define the "first" and "second" screen, is that the same order the OS is using, or do you want to be able to change it? I am assuming that you are using VLC in order to display the video, and not a VLC format - which, to my knowledge, does not exist.

Comment: I've completed the uipath training but I'm not sure as to how i can display it using 2 screens. I've already set up the flowchart by using clicks and double clicks to display the video but the monitor part I'm not so sure

Comment: Still not sure about the issue at hand. You do run UiPath on Windows, and you do have two monitors connected, correct? So, is the issue related to moving an application (VLC) to a particular screen, and then switch to full-screen mode?

Comment: I'm done with the video part but i can't drag and drop it to another monitor,i know it has something to do with hover and click down but i can't seem to do it